# ExtJS tree not populating with proxy store

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Here is my tree code:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    root: {
        expanded: true,
        children: [
            {
                text: "Group A",
                expanded: true,
                leaf: false,
                children: [{
                    text: 'Harry',
                    leaf: true
                },
                {
                    text: 'Steven',
                    leaf: true
                }]
            },
            {
                text: "Group B",
                expanded: true,
                leaf: false,
                children: [{
                    text: 'Tony',
                    leaf: true
                },
                {
                    text: 'Jason',
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
});

Ext.define('DHT.view.Category.CategoryList', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',      
    alias: 'widget.treeList',
    width: 200,
    height: 400,
    //store: store,
    store: ['DHT.store.Categories'],
    rootVisible: false
});
```

store code:

```
Ext.define('DHT.store.Categories', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'DHT.model.Category',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://localhost:52984/ExtJsRestfulService.svc/QuestionTypes',
        reader:
        {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'description'
        }
    }
});
```

model code:

```
Ext.define('DHT.model.Category', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'QuestionTypeID',
        dataType: 'int'
    },
    {
        name: 'Description',
        dataType: 'string'
    },
    {
        name: 'Deleted',
        dataType: 'int'
    },
    {
        name: 'ChangeDate',
        dataType: 'date'
    },
    {
        name: 'ChangeUser',
        dataType: 'string'
    },
    {
        name: 'Visible',
        dataType: 'bool'
    },
    {
        name: 'SortOrder',
        dataType: 'int'
    }],
    idProperty: 'QuestionTypeID'
});
```

I am unable to create a tree this way. It gives me an error: **TypeError: store.getRootNode is not a function**. If I create the tree with inline data i.e., replace //store: store, store: ['DHT.store.Categories'], with store: store, //store: ['DHT.store.Categories'], the tree populates without any problem. Can anyone point out what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The [store config](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-cfg-store) of your tree panel should either be an instance of `Ext.data.TreeStore` or - if you are in an MVC environment (which I assume by your class names) - the name of the store (without without the namespace `DHT.store`).

In any case, don't wrap the store in an array with square brackets `[]`.

```
store: Ext.create('DHT.store.Categories')
```

or

```
store: 'Categories'
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution I changed the store config to 'Categories'. But now it gives me another error "TypeError: store is undefined".

Comment: You should also extend your store from Ext.data.TreeStore instead of Ext.data.Store. Not sure if that will solve your error though. Also try using `Ext.create('DHT.store.Categories')` just to see if your store works at all.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution solved my problem but partially. I have posted another question regarding the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611324/unable-to-create-extjs-tree-from-json